# 438 runtime error when using the checkbox function in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get a 438 runtime error when using a checkbox on an Access 2007 form: 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. What is going wrong and how I can fix this?

[image]
    Private Sub Command133_Click()
    'On Error GoTo ErrHandle

```
' Save the Current Record
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False

' Exit the procedure if appointment has been added to Outlook.
If Me.chkAddedToOutlook = True Then
    MsgBox "This appointment has already added to Microsoft Outlook.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your check box control single control outside the option group frame ? OR you added control inside a option group frame ? if its control inside a option group, you will get error, 2427 you entered an expression that has no value.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to be more specific:

```
If Me!chkAddedToOutlook.Value = True Then
```

Edit:

```
'    ' Exit the procedure if appointment has been added to Outlook.
'    If Me.chkAddedToOutlook = True Then
'        MsgBox "This appointment has already added to Microsoft Outlook.", vbCritical
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

' Exit the procedure if appointment has been added to Outlook.
If Me!chkAddedToOutlook.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "This appointment has already added to Microsoft Outlook.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: If the checkbox is true then show a message box containing: "This appointment has already added to Microsoft Outlook". If not true, then do something else.

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't happen? Or?

Comment: Indeed that doen't happen. I dont get a messagebox.

Comment: When I go to the debugger then I see the text highlighted text in the picture.

Comment: And do you use a bang or a dot?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly with bang or a dot?

Comment: The exact syntax of my answer.

Comment: I found it. I use a dot!

Comment: And if you change that to a bang (exclamation sign)?

Comment: changing it to: If Me!chkAddedToOutlook = True Then doesn't fix this.

Comment: And if you use the full and explicit syntax - as noted in my answer?

Comment: Then you probably have misspelled the checkbox.

Comment: It results in the following error: The expression On Click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Moethod or data member not found.

Comment: no, I am 100% positive that the spelling is correct

Comment: Then the code modul may be corrupt. See my edit: Comment out the current and rewrite it - do not copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but that doesn't help either :(

Comment: That is weird. And the control is a CheckBox and when you type `Me.` the name of the CheckBox shows up in _IntelliSense_? Also, try to skip the `Dirty = False`.

Comment: Yes, it shows up when using IntelliSense so I am positive that there are no spelling errors. Skipping the Dirty = False part doesn't help

Comment: Sorry! I feel so stupid. When using the property sheet, I named the label of the Checkbox chkAddedToOutlook instead of the checkbox itself...

Comment: Oh, that explains.

Answer (score 0):

Your Original syntax if correct when you are using the code in a module on the form;

```
If Me.chkAddedToOutlook = -1 Then
```

I prefer to use the . as it allows the intellisense to work, and allows you to reference a property or a method which you can't do with the ! operator.

Comment: True and False in VBA are equal to -1 and 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get the same error.

Comment: As per Gustav - it sounds like either form or control corruption. Delete the control. Save and close the form. compact and repair the database. Go back to the form and create a new control - preferably called something different. Try the same code again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I got here because I had the same error. I had named the checkbox label ckDisableScroll instead of the actual control. Obviously labels can't be true of false. Once the error was corrected, everything worked as expected.